# rosserial too big for Arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, memory

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to add a magnetometer to my robot by plugging it into an Arduino and publishing the data using MagneticField message. I can't compile my code for Arduino Uno or Leonardo while at the same time using the [Adafruit Magnetometer driver](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified)  . I end up with this error message:

> Global variables use 2,675 bytes
> (104%) of dynamic memory, leaving -115
> bytes for local variables. Maximum is
> 2,560 bytes.

I only defined the necessary variables as globel (ros handle, publisher, message to publish and sensorlib instance). Did anybody figure out a way to work with such sensors on an Arduino and publishing their data using ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222964/rosserial-too-big-for-arduino/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2015-12-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Late response, but I guess this is a common problem. This solved my problem: http://answers.ros.org/question/28890/using-rosserial-for-a-atmega168arduino-based-motorcontroller/

Basically you can change the assigned buffer for serial communication by limiting the number of publishers/subscribers and also their length.

---

Originally posted by [lordricky](https://answers.ros.org/users/29169/lordricky/) with karma: 16 on 2017-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0